# Documents.Open FIleName:=StrIssueNext (defined) generates a Bad File Name error

Tags: vba, ms-word

Documents.Open FIleName:=StrIssueNext - the string is already defined as a fully pathed filename - D:\SInkers\OneDrive\Vol1\Winword\Bulletins\2099-11d.docx =- generates a Bad File Name error 4160 (Office 365 Home Word VBA)

It's from this section of commented code:

' Bulletin issue file names
    ' strEdition ' 2099-11c.docx file name only (strIssueNow has path)
    ' strNextIssue ' 2099-11d.docx file name only (strIssueNext includes path)
    strIssueNow = strODbullpath & strEdition  ' C/D:\Sinkers\OneDrive\VOL1\winword\bulletins\2099-11c.docx
    strIssueNext = strODbullpath & strNextIssue ' C/D:\Sinkers\OneDrive\VOL1\winword\bulletins\2099-11d.docx
    strIssueNow2 = strNObullpath & strEdition  ' C/D:\vol1\winword\bulletins\2099-11c.docx

```
' open next issue Word file to keep Word open, then open the current issue Word file for SaveAs

Documents.Open FileName:=strIssueNext    ' opening next issue to keep Word up
Documents.Open FileName:=strIssueNow     ' opening this issue for HTM conversion
Documents(strIssueNow).Activate          ' Focus on this issue for making HTM

' Doing it once in the OneDrive folder

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=strHTM, FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatFilteredHTML, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:= _
    True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:= _
    True, SaveNativePictureFormat:=True, SaveFormsData:=False, _
    SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=0

' Documents(strThisIssue).Close

Documents(strIssueNext).Activate
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
ActiveDocument.Save
Documents(strHTM).Close                                 ' close MHT file

' repeating for traditional

Documents.Open FileName:=strIssueNow ' opening this issue for HTM conversion
Documents(strIssueNow).Activate                        ' Focus on this issue for making HTM

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=strHTM2, FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatFilteredHTML, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:= _
    True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:= _
    True, SaveNativePictureFormat:=True, SaveFormsData:=False, _
    SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=0

Documents(strIssueNext).Activate
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
ActiveDocument.Save
Documents(strHTM2).Close                                 ' close MHT file
```

Comment: Is “ SInkers” (with an “l” a typo in your question? All the other pathnames lower down have “Sinkers” with an “i”. Not sure that would cause a 4160 though.

Comment: @slightlysnarky Most likely a typo as a small case "L" rather than a "i", which would be a bad file name. (VBA is not case-sensitive)

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes, it's an uppercase "i" , not a lowercase "l". So not a problem. (Not so easy to tell on the device I was using earlier!)

Comment: Yes, a typo in my question. S-i-n-k-e-r-s is the folder under which I place OneDrive, Dropbox and Google Drive